# Handle no such messageexception in Message source Spring

Tags: java, spring, message

I am using Spring Message source to load my property file.

```
String placeDetails = messageSource.getMessage(code,
                        null, new Locale(locale.toLowerCase()));
```

sample entry in property file:

```
BNA=Nashville:Nashville:USA
```

property file name:

```
placeDetails_locale.properties
```

The messagesource.getMessage method returns the assigned value ex If code "BNA"
String "placeDetails" will hold "Nashville:Nashville:USA".If the code not found in the property file it throws "No such message found exception".But I need to handle this situation like If no message found in that scenario I have to set the default value to placeDetails.

Approach I tried:
1.I need to check first If the code is available in that property file then only i need to call get messagesource method.But I am unaware on how to check the value presence through Message source
2.I need to define the default value look up in the catch block.

I tried second but not working as expected.Help me on how to check the availability of code in property file through Message source(first appraoch)

Comment: Rename it to something like `placeDetails.properties`

Answer (score 5):

Use below to return a default message in case you don't one. You don't have to handle exception cases.

```
getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can specify the default values for localized messages.

The preferred one is to provide a `placeDetails.properties` as well, that works as a catch all in case a given message key isn't found in `placeDetails_locale.properties`.

The second one (a quick fix) is to use the following overloaded `getMessage()` method

```
String placeDetails = messageSource.getMessage(code, null,
                      "placeDetails", new Locale(locale.toLowerCase()));
```

Notice, how the third argument specifies the default value in case the key lookup fails.

Comment: What happens if the message key isn't found in `placeDetails.properties`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `MessageSource` seems not to have a `containsMessageKey(String)` method or similar and in addition to that a `null` value as `defaultMessage` is getting ignored - in such case the `messageKey` will be returned.

I tried to solve that issue with the following approach:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private static final String messageKeyNotFound = "messageKey-not-found";

    public String getMessage(MessageKey messageKey, Locale locale) {
        String i18nMessage = messageSource.getMessage(messageKey.name(), null, messageKeyNotFound, locale);
        if (i18nMessage.equals(messageKeyNotFound)) {
            log.error("missing translation for messageKey '"+messageKey.name()+"' and locale '" + locale.getLanguage()+"'");
            return messageKey.name();
        }
        return i18nMessage;
    }

}
```

While MessageKey is an Enum containing valid keys.

```
public enum MessageKey {
    title,
    name,
    age;
}
```

With this solution the enum's and property's messageKeys need to have identical names

```
title=Title
name=Name
age=Age
```

You should write a unit test which iterates through all available keys and expected locales to catch any typos. But to be on the save side you will get error logs in case an unexpected locale comes in.